# Auto-selected text in a browser address bar

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, text

In windows when I click the address bar in Chrome or Firefox, or the search box in Firefox, all existing text is selected automatically and if I type something it is typed in a black text area.

But in Ubuntu, the text is not selected automatically, and I have to select all and then type.

Is there any option that fixes this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my system, when I press <kbd>F6</kbd> the contents of the address bar in Firefox are selected, just as you wish. The same behaviour with Iron (a derivate of Google Chrome).

To select the text (if any) on the search bar on Firefox, then you can press <kbd>F6</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

About the "black text area" I don't know; maybe you mean "blank text area", meaning that once you start typing, the (selected) text is substituted?

In Opera, you press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open a window where you can type a new URI.

For searches, I have configured several search keywords in [Opera's integrated search](http://help.opera.com/Linux/12.10/en/search.html#custom), so I simply press <kbd>F2</kbd> and type, for example, `d recipe`, to search for the word "recipe" on DuckDuckGo.com or `doi 10.1126/science.1100199` to go to [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1100199).

Comment: yes. substituted. great answer.

Answer (score 10):

A changable setting in Firefox governs text selection in the address bar.

Type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar, search for `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll` and change its value to `true` by double clicking.

You may also want to use `ctrl+l` or `alt+d` to autoselect text in the address bar, and `ctrl+k` to do the same in the search bar.

Answer (score 5):

#### Firefox

On the address bar write *about:config* and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Press the *I'll be careful* warning

[image]

On the search bar look for `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll` and change the value to **true**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Opera `Ctrl + L` works or `F8`. And also simple double click works in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Triple-clicking works for me to select the entire contents of the address bar.  But I like the F6 trick better now that I've heard about it.